# Corpus which includes smileys or even emojies

Tags: corpora

for a little project in University my group would like to have a look at how emojies or smileys are used in order to support or express irony, sarcasm or similiar.

Currently we are trying to find a prepared corpus where we can research exactly that, but I am not able to find anything useful. 
I tried to use Tworpus to generate a twitter corpus, but I only get an .xml file which needs to be POS-Tagged and Tokenized (and all that really is too much work for a 15-Minute presentation).

As I am fairly sure that no free corpus exists, which includes emojies, I have high hopes that a corpus, based on the world-wide-web, at least includes some smileys with which we can work.

Anyone got a tip? I tried the GlowBe Corpus but it seems like e.g. :) is not allowed as a word (syntax is wrong).

Kind regards